# Как можно реализовать многопоточность для цикла JS

Tags: javascript, python

У меня есть цикл for в JS, могу ли я как то реализовать его с помощью многопоточности или еще чего чтобы функция находящаяся в цикле выполнилась почти моментально, как например с помощью мультипроцессинга в Python

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: не то помоему, я получаю некоторые данные прям перед циклом, и на основе этих данных делаются вычисления в функции которая в цикле, то есть я не могу сделать промис из этого так как тогда сделаются неверные вычисления без еще неполученных данных. Допустим я получаю какое то письмо и мне надо посчитать количество букв в этом письме и разослать информацию о кол-ве сразу 20 людям, нужно ускорить сам процесс отправки людям, чтобы 20 итерация не ждала первой а выполнялось вместе с ней. В питоне это решалось мультипроцессингом, на джсе чет такого не вижу(

Comment: Какой-то слишком абстрактный вопрос. Например отправка 20 http-запросов в nodejs уже будет параллельной, если специально не добиваться обратного.

Comment: у меня не http у меня отправка транзакций в блокчейн, просто каждая итерация занимает какое то время, на python 20 итераций меньше чем за 0.3секунды совершались, тут не знаю как такое реализовать, грубо говоря надо совершить итерации в форе одновременно

Comment: @Strygwyr может сделать 2 цикла for? В первом создается массив промисов, в которых должны производиться вычисления. Потом делаете Promise.all, а потом уже перебираете массив результатов

Comment: уже разобрался, буду использовать child_process. Мне нужно чтобы вычисления сделались все на одном уровне, чтобы все 20 итераций выполнились на уровне одной, просто для каждой итерации будет разное вычисление.